# Issues when using WordPress rewrite rules then accessing parameter using get_query_var

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-wordpress-pages, query-variables

I'm developing a WP plugin and have a WordPress URL:

(e.g.: `http://localhost/testsite1/coder/?id=66`),

and have attempted to add a rewrite rule to

`http://localhost/testsite1/coder/66/`

using the following rule:

```php
function add_mypage_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^coder/([0-9]+)',
        'index.php?id=$matches',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action('init', 'add_mypage_rule');
```

I have registered a WP Query Var using:

```php
add_filter('query_vars', 'registering_custom_query_var');

function registering_custom_query_var($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

but when at URL `http://localhost/testsite1/coder/66/`, when I run code

`echo get_query_var('id');`

nothing is displayed

however when at URL `http://localhost/testsite1/coder/?id=66` the echo statement will display `66`.

What is wrong with my rewrite rule resulting in `echo get_query_var('id');` not accessing the parameter and displaying 66?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When you use `add_rewrite_rule` function, the first argument is the regular expression. Right? When you wrap your regular expression/pattern in parentheses, you're grouping the expression, which means you could access the captured group in the parentheses like this: `id=$matches[1]`.

- Regular expression `^coder/([0-9]+)`
- Access it in the first captured group (since the id is in the first parenthesis), `id=$matches[1]`

```php
add_action('init', 'add_mypage_rule');

function add_mypage_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^coder/([0-9]+)',
        'index.php?id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

2. After that, refresh the permalinks and rewrite rules by navigating to:
   `Settings > Permalinks > Click on the 'Save changes' button at the bottom of the page!`

And now it should, theoretically, work, unless there are more details that you have not mentioned in your question!

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again! Much appreciated!!

Comment: One last issue that I wonder if you can help with. When at the new URL `http://localhost/testsite1/coder/66/` the page layout reverts to the global Wordpress template and not to any layout (e.g. full width) changes I made to the original page. Is the page's CSS no longer being accessed and if so do you know the solution?

Comment: Sure, not a problem! As far as the layout goes, you could add/change/modify the layout based on a specific url. You could even add your custom css/javascript based on a specific url. There are multiple ways you could set it up, but I would usually use `template_redirect` hook and couple of conditional checks. There are tons of posts about `template_redirect` hook here on SO. If you find it hard to set this up, then feel free to open up a new question, others and I will try to help you out!